# Positive integral solutions of $\pi(x)+\pi(y)=2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Recently I was reading one of my earlier posts. [There](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210537/a-conjecture-on-the-prime-counting-function) it has been conjectured that,

> For all sufficiently large $x,y$ we have, $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)\le 2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

But it turned out to be false as shown there. Here $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $x$.

My question is,

> Is it true that for all sufficiently large $x,y$ we have either $\pi(x)+\pi(y)< 2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$ or $\pi(x)+\pi(y)> 2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$? In other words, does the equation, $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)=2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)$$has only finitely many positive integral solutions?

It seems to me that the answer to both questions are "yes" but I don't know how to prove this. Can anyone help?

Comment: If all of $x,x+1,\ldots,y$ are composite then $(x,y)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the number of integer solutions is infinite: 
For all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $$\pi(x)+\pi(x)=2\pi\left(\frac{x+x}{2}\right)$$